# Android Textview between layouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I wonder if anyone can help me before i rip my hair out, i've got an android layout that is perfect for what i need BUT with one problem , i have a few buttons at the top of the screen then a couple at the bottom, inbetween is a textview box but i need the bottom buttons to stay at the bottom of the screen, the top buttons to stay at the top and the textview to fill between, at the moment the textview is small but when data comes in and fills the textview box the bottom buttons expand then go off screen, i need the data to fill the textview then use scrollbars to scroll (or the 2 buttons)

code below

cheers in advance

Mark

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".70"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:text="Send RegID to email address"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".40"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Mark Morton(CSS)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".60"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Show ALL stored results"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Export List"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
    
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".40"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="Search results"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".40"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="DELETE ALL DATA"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="16dp" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@id/lblMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/lblMessage"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="38dp"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:text="Fast Scroll up"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="38dp"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:text="Fast Scroll down"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: don't fill_parent the textView. give it a fixed height, say 100dp and wrap it up in a ScrollView.. you should be good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".70"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:text="Send RegID to email address"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".40"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Mark Morton(CSS)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".60"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Show ALL stored results"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Export List"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".40"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Search results"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".40"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="DELETE ALL DATA"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="16dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewMessage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblMessage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="38dp"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:text="Fast Scroll up"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="38dp"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:text="Fast Scroll down"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Mate thats perfect youve saved my hair and sanity